# What is the font used for Spanish HBO subtitles?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

Hi someone can help to identify this font, it is
 used in HBO subtitles in spanish.
Thanks
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

Closest match appears to be [Nexa Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/font-fabric/nexa/bold/), according to [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=q&ch%5B1%5D=u&ch%5B2%5D=e&ch%5B3%5D=F&ch%5B4%5D=m&ch%5B5%5D=u&ch%5B6%5D=e&ch%5B7%5D=e&ch%5B8%5D=r&ch%5B9%5D=l&ch%5B10%5D=e&ch%5B11%5D=e&ch%5B12%5D=&ch%5B13%5D=g&ch%5B14%5D=p&ch%5B15%5D=a&ch%5B16%5D=r&ch%5B17%5D=l&ch%5B18%5D=i&ch%5B19%5D=&ch%5B20%5D=%C3%B3&ch%5B21%5D=&wtfserver=wtf_a_41&id=000687d7525581770006e6c300000576&glyphcount=22&imageid=0&x=118&y=38).

[image]

Comment: @JoseCarlosAlfaro - No Problem welcome to GD!

Comment: @JoseCarlosAlfaro I don't think this answer is right...see the comment in my answer. Also, check out Nexa's 'g' glyph, very different than what's in the screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a jagged, maybe extended, maybe bold Arial to me:

[image: screenshot of the text in question set in Arial]

The proportions are right, the 'a' looks a lot like an Arial 'a', the end of the 'r' seems to slant a bit just like Arial, and Arial is a really common font.

Comment: Subtitles are not exactly known for typographic excellence, or for being all that modern-looking! :P Nexa Bold is too modern-looking (no older than 2008 AFAICT) for an area of the TV that always feels like it's straight out of the early 90s (plus, the 'g' glyph is very different).